# ExtJs set window height

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

I am tring to dynamicaly set window height:

```
 component.remove(Ext.getCmp("comboBoxTypeOfSchool", true));
 component.remove(Ext.getCmp("comboBoxProgram", true));
 Ext.getCmp("winDecisionEditor").setHeight(190);
```

But, in browser i see that it sets height to "winDecisionEditor-body", not to "winDecisionEditor". How can I set height to "winDecisionEditor"?. Thanks in advance!

Here my decaration of window:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.decisionWindow', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

requires: [
    'Ext.form.Panel',
    'Ext.form.field.Date',
    'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    'Ext.form.field.Display',
    'Ext.button.Button',
    'Ext.form.FieldSet'
],

height: '',
id: 'winDecisionEditor',
margin: '',
width: 707,
layout: 'fit',
title: 'Create decision',
modal: true,

//Other stuff
});
```

UPDATE: fiddle for the issue

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12rh

Comment: That depends heavily on the layout you chose, so your code is incomplete. How did you define winDecisionEditor?

Comment: @Alexander, I have edited my question, but here I not set height during creation, and my problem disappear. Thank you for your response.

Comment: The inner element of a container with `fit` layout should be resized whenever the body of the container is resized, as can be seen here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12rc I don't know what you're trying, but setting height of the element is not your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is the layout. Layout fit is not the best choice for your page, because it fit the inner panel to the container (and not viceversa).

I think that if you would like to stretch the window to the inner items (and so change the size of the "items area" to the desired, that is in your example 190) you should use another layout. for instance in may example I'm using `layout:{type:'vbox', align:'stretch'}`.

Here i modify the original fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12ri

UPDATE:

Please consider the very important answer of
[Mitchell Simoens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925782/mitchell-simoens), that is

> Fit layout but didn't explain it properly. Fit layout takes the first
>   child component (only ONE) and fits it to the size of the container
>   (window in this case).
>
> That means, the first combobox will have the size of the window and
>   will not show the other items at all.  Fit layout will size the
>   container to it's child component.
>
> https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12rs
>
> Notice where the sizes are (or lack of sizes and autosizing happens)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't use vbox layout. Also, you were right about fit layout but didn't explain it properly. Fit layout takes the first child component (only ONE) and fits it to the size of the container (window in this case). That means, the first combobox will have the size of the window and will not show the other items at all. Fit layout will size the container to it's child component: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12rs Notice where the sizes are (or lack of sizes and autosizing happens)

Comment: @MitchellSimoens Sorry, i forgot to save my fiddle. I've updated my fiddle. I'm going to add your detailed answer in mine. I know that you are like god :D